# AngularJS Multiple ng-app within a single page

Tags: angularjs

Only the first ng-app works: see my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/T5VrHNNQJ5RlPnFML9kc)

How can I make both app work together? I understand that I should a line to bootstrap the modules, i'm not sure where exactly to add that line.

HTML

```
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.4.js"></script>
  <script src="clientsearch.js"></script>
  <script src="datepicker.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">


    <div ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
    <div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="appointment_start">Appointment start:</label>
                <p class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" id="appointment_start" name="appointment_start" class="form-control" readonly datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt1" is-open="opened1" max-date="'2020-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event,'opened1')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                  </span>
                </p>

           </div>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- ng-controller -->
    </div> <!-- ng-app -->



    <div id="appclientcomplete" ng-app="ui.bootstrap.clientautocomplete">
    <div ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
     <div class="row">
        <h4>Static arrays</h4>
        <pre>Model: {{selected | json}}</pre>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Type client's name, address or phone number" ng-model="selected" typeahead="client as client.first_name + ' ' + client.last_name + ' ' + client.address_1 + ' ' + client.address_2 + ' ' + client.city  for client in clients | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div> <!-- ng-controller -->
    </div> <!-- ng-app -->


    </div>  
</body>
```

datepicker.js

```
angular
  .module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap'])
  .controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {


});
```

clientsearch.js

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.clientautocomplete', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.clientautocomplete').controller('TypeaheadCtrl', function($scope, $http) {


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, Angular will only bootstrap the first `ng-app` it encounters. You should only use one app (module) but you can easily create a module that uses the other two modules.

```
angular.module("app", ["ui.bootstrap.demo", "ui.bootstrap.clientautocomplete"]);

ng-app="app"
```

Comment: It worked, added `<script>angular.module("app", ["ui.bootstrap.demo", "ui.bootstrap.clientautocomplete"]);</script>` to HEAD and `ng-app="app"` to BODY. Thanks!